# UIImageView image not updating on main thread from GCD

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I have a bit of code that takes a thumbnail, applies a `CoreImage` filter to it, then sets it to a custom `UITableViewCell's` `imageView` property:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
    ^{
        CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage imageWithCGImage:self.thumbnail.CGImage]retain];
        CIFilter *filter =    [[CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone" keysAndValues:
                                kCIInputImageKey, inputImage,
                                @"inputIntensity", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
                                nil] retain];
        CIImage *outputImage = [[filter outputImage] retain];
        CGImageRef cgimage = [self.context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
        filtersTableViewCellItem.thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimage];

        [filter release];
        [outputImage release];
        [inputImage release];
        CGImageRelease(cgimage);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        ^{
            UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [[self cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] retain];

            if (tableViewCell)
            {
                [filtersTableViewCell.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
                filtersTableViewCell.imageView.image = filtersTableViewCellItem.thumbnail;
            }

            [tableViewCell release];
        });
    });
```

The thumbnail is being produced properly, however it is not updating itself on the `imageView`. I've tried doing `setNeedsDisplay` to not avail. The funny thing is, when I've used similar code like this, but haven't used a custom `UITableViewCell`, it's worked perfectly fine. Anyone have any insight as to why this might not be working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening because I was doing some loading of the UITableViewCell in its layoutSubviews method (I was setting the frame of the UIImageView) and this was running into some conflict with my GCD thread. I moved all of this code to layoutSubviews and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try reloading that cell:

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPath:indexPath withAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]
```

Comment: reload cell not needed. refresh uiimageview should do it.

Comment: I'm not sure how that works. Updating the image of a UIImageView anywhere else in the app immediately shows results, but in a table cell it needs to be redisplayed (without having to reload the entire cell)? Why is that?

Comment: I failed to mention I'm using layout subviews to layout the subviews of my UITableViewCell and it might be that.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things for you to check -

First, is it possible you did not have a custom view set up for that nib file? I had the same problem. I created a UIview subclass for that view controller, went into Interface Builder and set the view to that UIView subclass and then added an import header for the UIView into the Controller class. thats what did it for me